# Can not run gitlab ci with Permission denied

Tags: ios, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, fastlane

[image]

When I try to run my gitlab-ci.yml, I got this error ?
Has anyone have any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**The Error:** `mkdir` command fails.
`mkdir` is a Linux/iOS command that **creates a new directory**.

When it throws the error:

> Permission denied

it tells that the **user running that command** (the user executing the script or running the process) **has no rights to create a directory** in

> /Users/nawinpoolsawad/builds/pxKER6-V/0/bitnance-exchange/exchange-ios.tmp

To fix the issue, change permission of the directory `/Users/nawinpoolsawad/builds/pxKER6-V/0/bitnance-exchange/` **and its parents** or execute that application/script with another user (eg `root`).

Comment: I already change permission to drwxr-xr-x but It still not working.

Comment: Does - for testing purposes - 777 (drwxrwxrwx) fixes the issue?